# AngularJS - nested component callback not making it past a component factory

Tags: angularjs, components

I am writing an app with Ionic 1.3.5 and AngularJS 1.5.3.

I have nested components and a component factory that decides which child component to render.

One child type has an onClick call back that I am trying to propagate to the parent. I keep getting this error:  Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '$ctrl' in Today

Here is my factory:

```
<clickable-list
    ng-if="$ctrl.type === 'clickableList'"
    on-click="$ctrl.onClick(value)"
    answer="$ctrl.answer">
</clickable-list>

<plain-text-answer
    ng-if="$ctrl.type === 'plainText'"
    answer="$ctrl.answer">
</plain-text-answer>
```

I was able to fix my Plunker so it runs and reproduces the error: http://plnkr.co/edit/ESTMPRRpdRuks6AJdRxv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your plunker does not work cause you must have spaces:

```
template: ['<component', 'value="1">', '</component>']
```

result in html `<componentvalue="1"></component>`

Second, your problem is how you chain calls passing `value`. To make it work without additional methods you need:

one component

```
<c1 ng-click="$ctrl.onClick({value: value})">
```

two components

```
<c1 on-click="$ctrl.onClick({value: value})">
<c2 ng-click="$ctrl.onClick({value: {value: value}})">
```

...

Since this is a bit retarded, it is better to create intermidiate methods:

```
c1: (onClick: '&')
vm.doClick = (value) => {
  vm.onClick({value: value});
}
```

then you have fancy html for c1: `<c2 ng-click="$ctrl.doClick({value: value})">`

http://plnkr.co/edit/27cCqsnACtdIz00PfI3E?p=preview correct plunk

Comment: This worked but in my real code base I need to go up a few more levels... I don't understand why it's necessary to wrap it several times or use intermediate methods.